# How to center a List(ul)

Tags: html, css

I have a `ul` List that contain some `li` elements and I float them to left. It currently looks like below;

| A | B | C | D | E < space empty>|

I  want it to be

| A | B | C | D | E |

that is center on the page and contents should be centered too

**HTML**

```
<div class="profile-content">
    <ul class="content-btn">
        <li>
            <div class="digits">83</div>Followers
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="digits">1507</div>Tweets
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="digits">234</div>Friends
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="digits">51</div>Likes
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="digits">42</div>Gits
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content-btn  {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.profile-content ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.profile-content ul li .digits {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Your CSS rules reference the `.profile-card` class but that is not included in the HTML you provided. Please make a JSFiddle or provide the all the applicable HTML. From what I see you are floating your `li` so that will prevent it from being centered unless you assign more rules to it.

Comment: [this will solve your answer](http://css-tricks.com/centering-list-items-horizontally-slightly-trickier-than-you-might-think/)

Comment: @RyanBrewer Please don't mind me, it is referenced, I just posted the above code for brevity but I have removed it from the codes above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.profile-content{text-align:center}` and istead *floating* the `li` elements, use `display:inline-block;`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5A2E/)

Note: there is no `.profile-card` in your HTML markup so I removed it from the CSS selector.

`.profile-content ul li{...}`

`.profile-content ul li .digits{...}`

Answer (score 1):

```
.content-btn  {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content-btn li{
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
    list-style:none;
}
.content-btn li:first-child{
    border-left: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
.profile-card .profile-content ul li .digits {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> jsfiddle.net/g33HN/

See this link. i hope this help for you